# directive not working in its own module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I declare my module in this way, I receive an error : "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]"

```
angular.module('myApp.resumeDirectives',[])

.directive('nameResume',[
  function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<h1 id="user-name">{{resume.name}} resume </h1>'
    };
  }
]);
```

this is the code in my directive file
and this is the code in my main file

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', [
  // ...
  'myApp.resumeDirectives'
]);
```

If, instead, I declare the directive this way, the directive works properly.

```
myApp.directive('nameResume',[
  function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<h1 id="user-name">{{resume.name}} resume </h1>'
    };
  }
]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you doing the last bit when you have already injected the directive into the myApp module.

Comment: is the .js file that this module is defined in listed in your HTML *before* or *after* the module injecting it?

Comment: I reworded the question slightly to make it more clear that it's two separate code samples.  However, I still believe the issue lies in the HTML where the `.js` files are declared, and not in this code.

Comment: @Claies - I read the question again after your comment and you're right. I misread the question the first time so I deleted my answer.. thanks for noticing

Comment: Ty Claies the .js file was there with a misspell ! Ty so much for letting me know that the problem is there

Comment: so you were able to solve your issue then? Very good!

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create a file declaring the module such as 
index.js or whatever name you want and declare the module

```
angular.module('myApp.resumeDirectives',[]);
```

then, inject the new file to your script files